# Groovy unable to resolve class

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I am stuck with running a simple groovy code example. I am using **eclipse**.

The code that I am trying to run is.

```
package com.app

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

class Demo {

static void main(String[] args) {
  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
  def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText ''' {"Integer": 12, "fraction": 12.55, "double": 12e13}'''

  println(obj.Integer);
  println(obj.fraction);
  println(obj.double); 
 }
}
```

When I am trying to compile this error is being thrown to the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at Json.main(Json.groovy:3)
```

I also attach a picture of the ide and the code here as well.

Anyway I can overcome this error?

Thank you.

[image: IDE with error]

Comment: It works for me in Eclipse. It is probably to do with how you set up Groovy in your IDE.

Comment: What version of Groovy Compiler are you using?  Groovy 2.5+ does not automatically include groovy.json package. You can expand Groovy Libraries node to see what is available.